# How to work audio call in pidgin?

Tags: ubuntu, pidgin

How to enable or work audio call in pidgin ? because i am not able to hear audio calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the other party hear you? Is it possible to choose wich output device Pdigin uses? Or can you set a 'default' audio device under ubuntu?

Example under windows:
My computer has 2 outputs (rear and front, which are different audio devices). I can set the default audio output to rear-panel, which has the lead to my amplifier. In Skype I can choose to use the output on the front panel instead (so I can plugin my headset without removing the lead to the amp). My guess is you have a similar situation.

Comment: No ..they also not able to hear it

Comment: So your mic isn't working either? What about using the rear panel to test if that works?

Comment: i have mic .. but my friend want to hear my voice . but she doesn't have that..